# Prove that if for any $A\subset F,A=f(f^{-1}(A))$, then f is surjective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $f:E\rightarrow F$ and for any $A\subset F,A=f(f^{-1}(A))$. Show that f is surjective.

What i have tried is 
$$\text{Let }y\in A $$
$$\{y\}\subset A$$
$$\{y\}= f(f^{-1}{\{y\})}$$
And i stuck here.

Any better alternative or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you've missed a step that makes it difficult for you to continue. Here is a little help: Assume $f$ is *not* surjective, and that $y\in F$ is a point that is not hit by $f$. *Then* you can start looking at $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ and at $f(f^{-1}(\{y\}))$. This should lead to a contradiction, which means that the two assumptions "$f$ is not surjective" and "for all $A\subseteq F, f(f^{-1}(A)) = A$" are incompatible.

Comment: I do not have idea how it leads to contradiction. Is it ok if i don't want use contradiction?

Comment: @AlanWang You can work to make the contradiction argument less visible, but I don't think that this result is even provable without using some form of argument by contradiction. Here are some more details on the proof I had in mind:  If $f$ is not surjective, then that means that there is at least one $y\in F$ such that no $x\in E$ gives $f(x) = y$. Then by definition of $f^{-1}$, we have $f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \emptyset$, the empty set. That means that $f(f^{-1}(\{y\})) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset \neq \{y\}$. This contradicts the condition $A\subseteq F, f(f^{-1}(A)) = A$.

Answer (score 0):

You can take $A$ to be any proper subset of $F$. For all $y\in F$, just take $A=\{y\}$ and see what the condition gives you. There is a special case when $F$ is a single element set though. That should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

$$\{y\}=f(f^{-1}(\{y\})$$ actually tells you that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ **cannot be empty** or equivalently that some $x$ must exist with $f(x)=y$.

It is true for each $y\in A$ so you are allowed to conclude that $f$ is surjective.